# Simple file recurser

Tags: c#, recursion, file

I'm using C# for a project and thought I would get a feel for the language by making some simple programs.  My current program is a simple file recurser that prints the names of files and directories.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace FileRecurser
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int indent = -2; // Start off at -2 so first indent
                                        // starts at 0.

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: recurser <directory>");
                return;
            }

            // Check if directory exists.
            string directory = args[0];
            if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0} doesn't exist!", directory);
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Printing files for {0}\n", directory);
            PrintDirectoryFiles(directory);
        }

        private static void PrintDirectoryFiles(string directory)
        {
            indent += 2;

            // If any subdirectories.
            string[] subdirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(directory);

            if (subdirectories.Length != 0)
            {
                foreach (var subdirectory in subdirectories)
                {
                    // Change color to reflect directory.
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;

                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "{0}{1}:",
                        new String(' ', indent),
                        Path.GetFileName(subdirectory)
                    );

                    Console.ResetColor();

                    PrintDirectoryFiles(subdirectory);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }

            // Print file names.
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory);

            if (files.Length != 0)
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "{0}{1}",
                        new String(' ', indent),
                        Path.GetFileName(file)
                    );
                }
            }

            indent -= 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like how you use static field to indicate level of indentation, I think it would be better if you passed it down the recursion in parameters of the methods.

And while you're at it, you should probably separate your concerns: don't have everything in your `Program` class, but have one class that recurses directories, and one that writes them out. That way, you can reuse them if you want to write the output in a different way (say in a GUI app) or if you want to recurse through something else than files (say, registry entries).

Also, there is no need to check whether a collection is empty before iterating it, it just unnecessarily clutters the code.

And you should think about handling exceptions: there might be directories you don't have access to. And there's also a chance that a directory was deleted while you were iterating its siblings, so you should handle that too.

Answer (score -1):

I would avoid using `return` to terminate when you are in `Main`, and use [Environment.Exit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx) instead.

It allows you to specify an error code (which is usually useless, but anyway), and also it makes your code easier to move to another method.

Comment: I think it makes your code *harder* to move to another method. If I call a method, I don't expect it to exist the whole application on failure.

Comment: well, it depends who you are coding for, but one of my motto for coding  is "fail fast, fail hard", and I like to have my app crash when something goes really wrong.
On second thought, I guess a better option would be to throw exceptions and leave them uncatched if you still want to crash the app.